# Как сравнить элемент массива с числом через цикл while?

Tags: python, list

Задание: В массив помещается два элемента: 1, 1. Затем необходимо заполнить массив, пока очередной элемент массива не станет больше 10. Условие: каждое следующее число должно быть суммой двух предыдущих чисел.

Мой код:

```
A = [1, 1]
I = 1
while A[I] < 10:
    I += 1
    A.append([I - 1] + [I - 2])

print(A)
```

Не могу найти ошибку.

Comment: Для начала поправьте отступы в коде в вопросе.

Comment: @wchistow, уже исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот правильный вариант кода:

```py
A = [1, 1]
I = 1
while A[I] < 10:
    I += 1
    A.append(A[I - 1] + A[I - 2])
    #        ^          ^

print(A)
```

Comment: @wchhistow, спасибо!

Comment: Условие цикла, вероятно, неправильное осталось

Comment: @ДанилаМастер, если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте этот ответ как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).

Comment: @MBo, нет, условие верное, см. условие: "*пока очередной элемент массива не станет больше 10*".

Comment: Ага, автор на ходу подметки меняет

Comment: Да. Я отредактировал условие. Просто я его сам сформулировал, так как задание было в виде блок-схемы, которую я тоже не сразу понял. Ответ @wchistow верный.

Comment: Строго говоря `>` и `>=` - это немного разные вещи. Условие, противоположное `>` - это `<=`, соответственно.